# Regex to convert Email to Name

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm after some assistance in converting an email address to a name using `preg_replace` in a long block of text.

My emails can follow two different structures:

1) firstname.lastname@domain.co.uk

or

2) firstname.middlename.lastname@domain.co.uk

To possibly make this more complicated, in the text email addresses start with @ so for example:

> The cat sat on the mat whilst @firstname.lastname@domain.co.uk watched in silence.

Should be:

> The cat sat on the mat whilst Firstname Lastname watched in silence.

```
preg_replace("/\B@(\w*[a-z_.]+\w*)/i", "$1", $text)
```

The code above seems to successfully capture the bit I need, but keeps the domain. I need to remove the domain and convert any periods to spaces.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your regex is overcomplicated, the format can be simplified to: `/@([^@\s]+)@[\w.\-]+/`.
2. I'm pretty sure I know what your next questions are going to be...
3. [`preg_replace_callback()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).
4. and...

```php
$in = 'The cat sat on the mat whilst @first.middle.last@domain.co.uk watched in silence.';

var_dump(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '/@([^@\s]+)@[\w.\-]+/',
        function($in) {
            $parts = explode('.', $in[1]);
            $parts = array_map('ucfirst', $parts);
            $name = implode(' ', $parts);
            $email = substr($in[0], 1);
            return sprintf('<a href="mailto:%s>%s</a>', $email, $name);
        },
        $in
    )
);
```

Output:

```
string(118) "The cat sat on the mat whilst <a href="mailto:first.middle.last@domain.co.uk>First Middle Last</a> watched in silence."
```

and ofc bear in mind that email addresses can be [virtually anything](https://emailregex.com/) and this gross oversimplification will probably have false positives/negatives and other fun bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this and it should work

```php
$text="The cat sat on the mat whilst @firstname.middlename.lastname@domain.co.uk watched in silence @firstname.lastname@domain.co.uk.";


echo preg_replace_callback("/\B\@([a-zA-Z]*\.[a-zA-Z]*\.?[a-zA-Z]*)\@[a-zA-Z.]*./i", function($matches){
    $matches[1] = ucwords($matches[1], '.');
    $matches[1]= str_replace('.',' ', $matches[1]);
    return $matches[1].' ';
}, $text);

// OUTPUT: The cat sat on the mat whilst Firstname Middlename Lastname watched in silence Firstname Lastname
```

Answer (score 0):

If the email could contain an `@` and start with an optional `@`, you could make the match a bit more restrictive starting with an optional @ and add whitespace boundaries `(?<!\S)` and `(?!\S)` to prevent a partial match.

Note that `[^\s@]` by itself is a broad match matching any char except a @ or whitespace char

```
(?<!\S)@?([^\s@]+)@[^\s@]+(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kX6uGR/1)

For example (using php 7.3)

```
$pattern = "~(?<!\S)@?([^\s@]+)@[^\s@]+(?!\S)~";
$strings = [
    "firstname.lastname@domain.co.uk",
    "firstname.middlename.lastname@domain.co.uk",
    "The cat sat on the mat whilst @firstname.lastname@domain.co.uk watched in silence."
];
foreach ($strings as $str) {
    echo preg_replace_callback(
            $pattern,
            function($x) {
                return implode(' ', array_map('ucfirst', explode('.', $x[1])));
            },
            $str,
    ) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```
Firstname Lastname
Firstname Middlename Lastname
The cat sat on the mat whilst Firstname Lastname watched in silence.
```

[Php demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/440cd3f7a937638669b6b6e13fe0631fe7adc817)